# Matrix type IQ puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

Found these tasks, although not looking too advanced, I can't seem to solve them.

What are the solutions and why?

Task 1

[image]

Task 2

[image]

Comment: These seem hard to me, not intermediate. Do you have more info on your source?

Comment: mmmm bit.ly/2lLMyAo
i think it may be part of "high-end" iq tests without time limit and someone trying to cheat :)

Comment: Nope, not a high-range test. It is used in some textbooks I have heard when I got the tasks.

Comment: For instance, if you do a Google image search, you won't find these tasks anywhere else, because of it.

Comment: @glorfindel, I have found out that these images are copyrighted and were posted without knowledge of this and permission. Thus, please do delete.

Comment: I can't delete them, you'll have to file a request via the Contact Us form.

Comment: Also, you should contact the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170301211620/http://puzzling.stackexchange.com:80/questions/49495/matrix-type-iq-puzzle-intermediate) since they have illegal copies as well.

Answer (score 3):

One way of visualizing the pattern in the second question is

> [image: Second series]

since then

> the red bar rotates clockwise 90° while the green stands still first, and the rotates clockwise 90° for each column. I'll admit it is a bit of a stretch though :-)

For the first question, depending on how well-designed the test is,

> it *could* be the second choice (the empty box with black blob below) since then the parity (odd/even) of white and black outer blobs are the same (on each row) and the number of blobs are equal in the left and right-most column (i.e., 3,3; 3,3; 1,1) are equal on each row. That is the only reasonable pattern I could find...

Answer (score 2):

Task 1,

The answer is

> the third answer from the left,

because,

> based on the pattern of the white wings relevant to the square, they rotate 90 degrees clockwise intact, then lose the opposite white wing and rotate 90 degrees clockwise again, rotate 90 degrees clockwise intact, lose the other white wing and rotate 90 degrees, rotate again as is, gain a wing back at next 90 degree rotation, rotate again intact, so the questionable position it should gain another wing with the last 90 degree rotation.  The only choice with both white wings intact sideways is the third answer from the left. For the black wing showing up on the bottom in the answer there must be a larger pattern present beyond the sets of objects shown.  For the dot not present in the answer is due to every other pattern of presence.

Task 2,

The answer is

> the fourth one from the right,

because,

> it follows the pattern of from top to bottom first row, the 2nd radius present clockwise gets moved 90 degrees clockwise, then the entire object is rotated 90 degrees, then in the second column the first radius is moved 90 degrees clockwise and then the entire object is rotated 90 degrees, so in the last column it is back to the second radius to be moved 90 degrees clockwise and then the entire object moved clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem,

> The "dot" in each row gives the square an extra "wing" in comparison to the other non-dot containing squares in the row.

With that rule in place, the deducible answer should be

> #2

Question might be flawed though.